# Sequel format for constants, functions calls in select?

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

I'm trying to figure out how to create a [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) Dataset that contains function calls and constants as part of its `select` and uses aliases.  I'm stuck on the proper syntax.

I'm trying to avoid inserting raw SQL but I will if I have to as long as I can chain the resulting dataset and refer to column aliases inside the raw SQL.

My actual query is more complicated (and I'm not actually calling `sin`, it's just an example of a function call), but for illustrative purposes, here's a stripped down version of what I'm trying to do in SQL:

```
SELECT
  0 AS a,               -- constant
  sin(t.x) AS b,        -- function call with aliased column value argument
  t.x AS c
FROM
  T AS t
;
```

What would the equivalent, idomatic, Sequel be?  So far I have:

```
DB[:T.as(:t)].
    select(
        #0 as a,        # How? constant
        #sin(t.x) as b, # How? function call with aliased column value argument
        :t__x.as(:c)
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a more concise way, you can use implicit aliasing using symbols with a triple underscore, use just the select method with a virtual row block:

```
DB[:T___t].select('0'.lit.as(:a), :t__x___c){sin(t__x).as(b)}
```

This isn't exactly the same as the order of the selected columns differs, but that usually doesn't matter.

Comment: Cool.  BTW: are there any guarantees on the order of SELECTs in the resulting SQL compared to the order in Sequel expressions?  For instance (on PostgreSQL) `DB[:T___t]{setseed(t__id)}{random{}.as(mysort)}`  [sorry if this isn't correct syntax] I want to make sure `setseed` always happens *before* `random`.

Comment: The method arguments (the stuff in (...)) come before the whatever is returned by the block (the stuff in {..}).  For your case, you want to use a block for both: `DB[:T___t].select{[setseed(t__id), random{}.as(mysort)]}`

Comment: `lit` method doesn't exist here... where is it from??

Comment: ah ok, got it from https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/extensions/core_extensions.rb

Answer (score 0):

After much poking around in the excellent [Sequel docs](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html), I came up with the following solution that worked for me:

```
DB[:T.as(:t)].
    select_more('0'.lit.as(:a)).
    select_more(:sin.sql_function(:t__x).as(:b)).
    select_more(:t__x.as(:c))
```

If anyone knows a more concise or idiomatic way to express this, please share.